# Cauchy Principal Value and Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am fiddling around with Kramers-Kronig relations, and for that I need to use the Principal Value. I have the following notebook, where I take the dispersion `disp` and from that find the absorption using the Kramers-Kronig relation.

When I compare the resulting absorption to the analytical expression for the absorption, I see that the widths of are not the same after normalizing - which they should be. Is there a setting/parameter I am missing?

```
\[CapitalGamma] = 50 10^3;
disp[\[CapitalDelta]_] := 
  1/\[Pi] \[CapitalDelta]/(\[CapitalDelta]^2 + (\[CapitalGamma]/(4 \
\[Pi]))^2/4);
abs[\[CapitalDelta]_] := 
  1/\[Pi] (\[CapitalGamma]/(4 \[Pi]))/(\[CapitalDelta]^2 + (\
\[CapitalGamma]/(4 \[Pi]))^2);


absKK[\[CapitalDelta]_] := -NIntegrate[disp[x]/(
     x - \[CapitalDelta]), {x, -Infinity, \[CapitalDelta], Infinity}, 
     Method -> PrincipalValue, Exclusions -> Automatic, 
     MaxRecursion -> 100] // Quiet;


max = \[CapitalGamma];
step = 100;


absVals = {}; dispVals = {};
For[i = -step, i < step + 1, i++,
  \[Delta] = max*i/step;
  absVals = Append[absVals, {\[Delta], absKK[\[Delta]]}]];

Show[
 ListLinePlot[absVals, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}],
 Plot[-6.5 abs[\[CapitalDelta]], {\[CapitalDelta], -\[CapitalGamma], \
\[CapitalGamma]}, PlotRange -> Full]]
```

Comment: where is the term `1/pi` in your integral? Is it the factor that you have included in the analytic definition of `abs`?

Comment: The 1/pi at the integral is just a scaling factor. I can include it, but then I would have to multiply by 6.5/pi ~ 2 in order for the amplitudes to be equal. The widths will still differ. The 1/pi at the analytical expression is for normalization

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got your analytic expression for the absorption from but could it maybe be erroneous? If you replace `\Delta` with `2 \Delta` the issue seems resolved

```
1/\[Pi] (\[CapitalGamma]/(4 \[Pi]))/((2 \[CapitalDelta])^2 + (\[CapitalGamma]/(4 \[Pi]))^2);
```

Comment: I believe the absorption expression is correct. It is stated in this link also (first equation, page 3): http://nit.colorado.edu/atoc5560/week4.pdf. It is a standard Lorentzian